# R:open mnist label file

Tags: r, label, mnist

recently I am doing a project related to image recognition. And I am trying to use the MNIST dataset. I have already got some help with how to open the image file of the dataset(using readBin) but was stuck in how to open the label file. I used

```
to.read.label = file("~/train-labels.idx1-ubyte", "rb")
```

to get the connection but I dont know what to do next. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have worked it out by myself. It is actually the same idea. Just write a loop to get one number by a single time.